# Parse Nested JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, foreach

I've look high and low for a solution for this, but haven't found anything that is exactly what I am running into.  I am using php to parse a JSON response that is nested in a way that makes it difficult to extract specific fields.

Here is a bit of the JSON:

```
{
    "collection":{
    "items":[
        {
            "href":"https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/members/MEMBERID",
            "data":[
                "name":"id",
                "value": 0000000 // MEMBERID
            },
            {
                "name":"type",
                "value":"member"
            },
            {
               "name":"address_city",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "name":"address_state",
               "value":""
            },
```

Here is my php:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$result = json_decode($json);
foreach ($result->collection->items as $items=>$val) {
    foreach ($val->data as $data=>$datasets) {
        foreach ($datasets as $dataset=>$val) {
            echo $dataset.': '.$val;
            echo "<br>";  
        }
    }
};
```

and this is a bit of the current output:

```
name: id
value: MEMBERID
name: first_name
value: MEMBERNAME
name: last_name
value: MEMBERNAME
```

what I want to do is be able to list all of the members in this response with their first and last name.  I have tried using $val->first_name, $val['first_name']; and such but all result in a foreach error.

Comment: That JSON structure you posted is invalid. You cannot close an array opened with a square brace with a curly brace as done below the MEMBERID value.

Comment: That is just a sample and I changed the actual member id to protect security.  I have updated the json in my code above

Comment: Certainly that is just an example. But still it is invalid. We cannot help to fix your code if the structure of the data is invalid, thus unclear.

Comment: You're probably missing an opening curly brace (`{`) before your first `data` member.

Comment: I am not writing the json, it is coming from another server.  I am trying to parse the json with php.

Comment: Thing is: you might aswell post valid json that you're trying to parse to make this a complete, coherent question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data provided is obviously invalid which does not allow for a clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can ensure every `data` member has a `name` and `value` field you can use something like this and skip a for-loop:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$result = json_decode($json);
foreach ($result->collection->items as $itemKey => $val) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($val->data as $dataKey => $dataset) {
        $data[$dataset->name] = $dataset->value;
    }
    var_dump($data);
};
```

Although you should probably check for `$result->collection` and `$result->collection->items` first before looping over them to avoid errors.

Comment: That resulted in the following error:  Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: Be sure to check the variable names, I renamed the key in the foreach loop from `$data` to `$dataKey` - make sure you don't overwrite the array there.

Comment: Ok so that resulted in an array output of the entire string. How do I access a single variable like first_name?

Comment: It's just a normal array, just use `$data["first_name"]` after the loop, if it was part of the dataset it'll be in the `$data` array afterwards.

Comment: You sir, are the bomb!